# Understanding cmp in python and recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with some existing code that redefines equality (via a `__cmp__` method) for a class. It doesn't work as expected and in trying to fix it I've come across some behavior I don't understand. If you define `__cmp__` on a class that just calls the built in function `cmp`, then I would expect it to always hit the maximum recursion depth. However if you try to compare an instance of the class to itself it returns 0.

Here's the code:

```
class A:
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self, other)

a = A()
b = A()
cmp(a, a) # returns 0
cmp(b, b) # returns 0
cmp(a, b) # results in RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The RuntimeError I understand, but I don't understand why the first two calls to `cmp` succeed.

I've read through the [data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) section of the python docs and other things like this nice breakdown of [python equality](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/) but can't find an answer to this recursion.

And, yes I understand that as written this is a totally pointless class. The code I'm working with tries to redefine equality in certain situations and otherwise falls through to a basecase. The basecase doesn't work as implemented and so I am trying to fix it. I thought calling `cmp` might work and discovered this issue. I'm hoping that understanding this will help me with finding a suitable solution.

Comment: I tried the same code but didnt get any error

Comment: @AswinMurugesh - what version of Python are you using? I'm using 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where two names reference the same object, they are equal by definition (**edit**: at least as far as `cmp` is concerned, where "equal" really means "neither greater than nor less than").

Comment: Not necessarily. `float('nan')` isn't equal to itself.

Comment: @user2357112: There's a thread about the behaviour of `cmp` with `NaN` here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-May/044885.html which I'm afraid I don't have time to read to its conculsion.  :-)  I did get as far as Tim Peters saying "cmp(x, y) doesn't make sense for objects having only a partial ordering, so
I don't care [what] cmp() does with a NaN."

Comment: Ok, I did some more testing based on this answer. Looks like `cmp(a, a)` doesn't even call the `__cmp__` method. It just shortcuts to returning 0. Which means that `cmp(x, x)` is not always the same as `x.__cmp__(x)`. Somewhat confusing but understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the semantics of `cmp` require that the objects being compared have an ordering relationship (i.e. exactly one of the following is true in a `cmp(x, y)` call: `x < y`, `x == y`, or `x > y`), `cmp` can assume that an argument is equal to itself and skip calls to any comparison methods if the arguments are the same object.

(A lot of things in Python assume that for any object `x`, `x == x`. This sometimes causes bugs (especially with NaN floating-point values), but most of the time, it's a useful optimization. In the case of `cmp`, it's fine, since `cmp` requires `x == x` as a precondition to `cmp(x, x)`.)

Comment: You could (if you were crazy) define equality in such a way that `x == x` is `False`, yet `cmp(x, x)` would still return 0. But what you are saying is that `cmp` assumes you are not that crazy.

Comment: @ChrisPalmer: That's exactly the case with `NaN`, as user2357112 points out.  But of course `NaN` *is* crazy, so that's all right.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`cmp(a,a)` is calling the built-in `cmp`.  Without looking at source, I'm guessing that `self is other` check is made without calling the class `__cmp__`.  If the two objects are not identical, *then* `__cmp__` is called.